# Unable to call SetOnClickListener

Tags: kotlin, android-activity

[image]

[image]

Unable to run OnSetClickLestiner

Comment: Clicking Button does not go to second screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I can see you cant find the button with the id. You have to options

1st option: go to ur code and use the line

```
val myButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
myButton.setOnClickListener{
...
}
```

2nd option: go to gradle.app file and add into the plugins the line:

```
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

and then keep the same code as you have

Comment: The second option appears have worked is that because the android version I am using 4.1.2, doesn't include some the legacy features and by using id 'kotlin-android-extensions' refers back to out of use features?

Comment: the android studio has change some things from the older versions. This functionality was available in the older versions but in the newer ones it is disabled by default. your can also check the documentation for the version you have

Answer (score 0):

Follow this format when calling  **setOnClickListener**
Always initialize your Button variables before calling them.

---

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);
 
          Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
          button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
              }
          });
      }
}
```